# Call method x times using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to call one method 3 times Using **LINQ**, the method returns an object, with that object I want to add it into a List, How do i do it?

```
List<News> lstNews = new List<News>();

lstNews.Add(CollectNews) [x 3 times] <-- Using Linq 

private static News CollectNews(){
...
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you have to use Linq?

Comment: Maybe Are you confusing Linq with Lambda expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand you want to end up with a list of three `News` objects. You can do something like

```
Enumerable.Repeat(1, 3).Select(_ => CollectNews()).ToList();
```

You could use any value in place of `1` in that example.

While this approach works, it's sort of abusing the idea of LINQ. In particular, you should not assume any order of executing `CollectNews()` calls. While the standard `Select` implementation will execute in sequence this may not always be true.

Answer (score 8):

```cs
var lstNews = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 3).Select(_ => CollectNews()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `System.Linq.Enumerable` to repeat an Action multiple times.

```
            Enumerable.Repeat<Action>(() =>
            {
                lstNews.Add(CollectNews);
            }, 3).ToList();
```

This would run the `Add` method on the list 3 times. Docs on `Enumerable.Repeat` [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=netframework-4.8)